# Check if a sentence is the same forward and backwards

Tags: java

I am trying to check if a sentence is the same forwards and backwards or a  "sentence palindrome." The sentence "You can cage a swallow, can't you, but you can't swallow a cage, can you?" should return as a palindrome. Ignore everything that is not a letter.

My code: I know there are extra parts that are not necessary but I am trying to test different things. I will shorten and optimize after I figure out how to get it to work. The first for loop reads the characters and puts them into two different queue's and a stack. After I have a method called reverseWords2 which takes the words in a string and prints them in reverse order.

My problem: With the code I currently have here, everything returns true. My thinking was putting the characters into q and q2, then reversing the words of q2 and then comparing the two would work out. There is some problem and I am not sure how to fix it.

Update: Changed my q's to double ended q's. Now I just need to find out to correctly compare words and not just letters. Suggestions?

My code:

```
public static boolean isWordPalindrome(String input) {

      Deque<Character> q = new LinkedList<>( );
      Deque<Character> q2 = new LinkedList<>( );
      Queue<Character> q3 = new LinkedList<>( );
      Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>( );
      Stack<Character> throwaway = new Stack<>();
      Character letter;   // One character from the input string
      int mismatches = 0; // Number of spots that mismatched
      int i;              // Index for the input string
      int x;

      for (i = 0; i < input.length( ); i++)
      {
     letter = input.charAt(i); // read next character in the string
         if (letter.toString().equals(',') || letter.toString().equals('"') || letter.toString().equals('?') || letter.toString().equals('!') || letter.toString().equals('.')) {
             throwaway.add(letter); //ignore above chars and put in throwaway stack
         }
         if (Character.isLetter(letter) || letter.toString().equals(' ')) // if letter or space
         {
            q.add(letter);
            q2.add(letter);
            s.push(letter);
         }
      } // end of for loop
      reverseWords2(q2.toString()); // reverse the words of q2

      while (!q.isEmpty( ))
      {
         if (!Objects.equals(q.remove(), q2.removeLast()))
            mismatches++;
      }


      // If there were no mismatches, then the string was a palindrome.
      return (mismatches == 0); 
   }
```

Comment: 2 Qs and a stack? Why not one Q and just pull the word off each end and see if they are the same or not?

Comment: Use `Objects.equalsIgnoreCase()` (what is `Objects` anyway?) which is implemented to be the equivalent of `q.remove().equalsIgnoreCase(q2.remove())`, or something like that. You should also post the source for `reverseWords2()`.

Comment: There are many problems with this code. You are using what looks like a `java.util.Stack`, which [should not be used](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) under almost any circumstances. Your algorithm is overcomplicated. My IDE gives 9 warnings for this code and describes how to fix them - are you using an IDE?

Comment: @john3136 to check if a word is a palindrome it was easy to use 1 q and a stack to compare (left the code in there for now since I was testing).
I like your suggestion, but what would be an easy way to read the words at the end of the q?

Comment: @Jace Find a data struct that lets you pick from either end like a double ended queue.

Comment: You can really just split into an array of words: `public static boolean isWordPalindrome(String input){
    input = input.replace(",","");
    String[] arr = input.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length/2; i++){
      if(!arr[i].equals(arr[arr.length-i-1]))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }`

Comment: More fundamentally, `reverseWords2(q2.toString());` is not going to modify `q2` at all, thus when you come to compare `q` and `q2` are always identical.

Comment: @Jace You are using `LinkedList`, which does in fact already implement the `Deque` (double-ended queue) interface. All you need to do is change the declared type of your variables to use `Deque` methods.

Comment: @KenY-N can you explain why q2 is not modified? It makes sense since everything was returning true. 
   public static String reverseWords2(String sentence) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentence.length() + 1);
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(words[i]).append(' ');
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);  // Strip trailing space
    return sb.toString();
}

Comment: You pass in a `String` to `reverseWords()`, so that will have no effect on `q2`. You need to make `Queue<Character>` a parameter.

Comment: @KenY-N okay I updated the post slightly. So using suggestion from some of the comments, I have the two deque's q and q2. Now I compare the first char of q with the last char of q2. How can I correctly compare words?

Answer (score -1):

Change `Deque<Character>` to `Deque<String>`. Then, you can add a word to `Deque`.